# what is a deployment descriptor and do i really have to care about it when using Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

actually, what is a deployment descriptor?

do i really have to care about it when using Netbeans, cause i read something that it was optional. and that you could use annotations instead of configuring in xml files?

could someone give me the whole picture of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A deployment descriptor (likely web.xml in your case, since I think you posted an earlier question about building a webapp) tells the application container how the web app should be configured.  This is where you register your servlets and filters, add context parameters, and lots of other useful things.

Here is a link that describes the various parameters and their uses:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html

If you read that it is optional in NetBeans, it may be the case that NetBeans provides a default for you (maybe it lets you register your servlets through the IDE).  Still, it's good to know what goes on in web.xml in case you ever build a webapp without using NetBeans, or need a lower level of configuration than NetBeans provides.

Comment: the link u provided was for oracle. is this the same thing if im using glassfish?

Comment: Yes. `web.xml` is a J2EE standard.

Comment: and then we got application.xml too. and some other .xml files. are all these using same values or will i have to look these up as well?

Comment: it looks like a front end controller. redirecting which url-path to which servlet. couldnt they just have said that as an example instead of just throwing out empty words=) so typically in the java world. They have forgotten what KISS means.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by front end controller.  Mapping url paths to servlets is one thing that happens in web.xml, but certainly not the only thing.

Answer (score 1):

Deployment descriptor (web.xml) helps us to configure and provide mapping for URL's to respective servlets or JSP's. 
It is the configuration file used to specify security filters, error page handlers, default pages etc..

Refer this link for clear documentation: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml

Comment: Check this link for all possible deployment descriptor elements and its description: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html